# Как cпарсить конкретные данные из общего класса?

Tags: android, html, jsoup, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте!

Я использую библиотеку jsoup для парсинга html страниц сайтов.
Например, если мне нужно получить значение из класса information.

```
<div class="information"> Кот </div>
```

Я делаю так:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
Elements i = doc.getElementsByClass("information");
```

Получается, все, что обернуто в класс information, мы получим на выходе "Кот".
НО если "Кот" не единственное значение, которое обернуто в класс information. Например, если на одной странице находится другое, в том же классе? Например, такая картина:

```
// Здесь код HTML (всякие доктайпы,кодировки,тайтлы,дескрипшены,подключение скриптов и т.д.)
----------
----------
// Начинается блок с инфой
<div class="information"> Кот </div>
// Далее куча других классов
----------
----------
// И опять блок,только с другой инфой,но с тем же классом
<div class="information"> Хомяк </div>
----------
----------
```

Думаю, суть понятна. Т.е. если я напишу хоть два раза одно и то же:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
Elements i = doc.getElementsByClass("information");
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
Elements i = doc.getElementsByClass("information");
```

то на выходе я все равно получу значение, которое идет первым, т.е. на выходе будет

> "Кот" "Кот"

Теперь вопрос! Как пролистать или перепрыгнуть на место, где находится "Хомяк"?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: for (Element element : i) {
    System.out.println(element.ownText());
}

Будем вам и "Кот", и "Хомяк"

Comment: @Kroshandowski, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Тут по-быстрому накидал пример парсинга курса валют с mail.ru с одинаковым классом для доллара и евро. "w-quotations__item"

    Document document = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
    Elements nodeCityTemp = document.getElementsByClass("w-quotations__item");       
               
В итоге получаю только доллар,а евро нет.

Comment: хоть УРЛ дайте, с которого парсите

Comment: @metalurgus, главная страница mail.ru

Comment: @Kroshandowski, ну, все отлично работает. покажите больше кода. Как вы узнаете, что в nodeCityTemp только 1 элемент?

Comment: @metalurgus, я знаю, что работает..., но ведь тот же класс, в котором обернут доллар, обернут и евро (w-quotations__item). Если применить код выше, то на выходе я получаю только информацию по доллару. А как мне, так скажем, нужно перепрыгнуть через "w-quotations__item" на следующий "w-quotations__item", который содержит в себе информацию по евро.

Comment: @Kroshandowski, **повторю еще раз**. Покажите больше кода. Где вы получаете информацию о долларе?

Answer (score 3):

Elements это обертка для List<Element>, то есть списка элементов.  
Код вида

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
Elements i = doc.getElementsByClass("information");
```

вернет вам в i список всех элементов с классом "information". Итерируйтесь через него. С ним можно работать точно так же, как и со списком. Там будет и кот, и хомяк, и остальные жирафы и коровы.

Answer (score 2):

я бы вам посоветовал использовать селекторы. сам не так давно сталкивался с такой задачей. более того, чтобы не мучиться и не дебажить, можно испытывать селекторы онлайн http://try.jsoup.org/

вот вам рабочий селектор для получения доллара и евро `div[id=currency:usd], div[id=currency:eur]`

Comment: @Andreich, в данном случае я, может, не самый хороший пример привел. Да, вы правы, что в данном случае можно спастись, используя div id, но бывает так, что есть только div class и то единственный для всех элементов.

Comment: а что мешает сделать селектор по классу?

Comment: @Andreich, так класс-то один, т.е. общий. И доллар обернут в "w-quotations__item", и евро обернуто в "w-quotations__item".
И теперь я не знаю, как перепрыгнуть через класс, чтобы добраться до евро. Возможностью парсинга по id, как в данном случае, пренебрежем.
 
P.S. Парсинг курсов валют на mail.ru я привел для примера, т.к. там наглядный пример обертки элементов одинаковым классом.

Comment: значит анализировать и выделять какую-то отличительную черту, по другому никак не сделать